# The title container color is also changing , how to fix this so that the container color do not change?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]The container color(kcardcolor) is also changing on expanding it , how to fix this so that the container color do not change?

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: Container(
        color: kCardColor,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          collapsedTextColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 29, 29),
          title: Text(
            'Notification',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          iconColor: Colors.black,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Hey',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

delete that line : backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 29, 29),

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: Container(
        color: kCardColor,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          collapsedTextColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text(
            'Notification',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          iconColor: Colors.black,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Hey',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color:Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: the container color(kcardcolor) is changing to white on expnading the tile , is there any way so the color do not change?

Comment: Don't give background color to ExpansionTile, just assign value to container